# Why is tikz getting a different \linewidth or drawing a different rectangle inside a minipage under the same conditions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, width, tikzmark

## Question

I have a signature macro that determines whether to include a signature for a final production or whether to put in a red unsigned box (for pre-production copies). For some unknown reason, the rectangles are not being drawn equally.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,tikzmark}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\myswitch{Not for production!}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mysignature}{ m m O{0} O{.8\linewidth} O{0pt} O{0pt} }{
    \IfEq{\myswitch}{Not for production!}
        {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
            \path [anchor=south west,draw,red,dashed] ($ (pic cs:#1) + (0,-3mm) $) rectangle (\linewidth,4cm) node [anchor=center,pos=.5,font=\bfseries\large] {UNSIGNED};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
        {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
            \node [anchor=south west,rotate=#3,xshift=#5,yshift=#6] at (pic cs:#1) {\includegraphics[width=#4]{#2}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{A-sig-left}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Dr. Joe Schmoe\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Managing Director
\mysignature{A-sig-left}{sig1.eps}[1][\linewidth][0mm][-12mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{A-sig-right}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Billybob Janice\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Head of Peanut Gallery
\mysignature{A-sig-right}{sig2.eps}[1][.8\linewidth][5mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{B-sig-left}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Dr. Joe Schmoe\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Managing Director\\
\mysignature{B-sig-left}{sig1.eps}[1][\linewidth][0mm][-12mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{B-sig-right}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Billybob Janice\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize
Head of Peanut Gallery\\
}
\mysignature{B-sig-right}{sig2.eps}[1][.8\linewidth][5mm]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: unrelated to the question but it's a bad idea to have a font size change like `\footnotesize` without having a `\par` before the group ends, it means you get footnotes size text on a normal size baseline.

Comment: You probably are also missing several `%` from ends of lines, in particular the lack of `%` after `\end{minipage}` means there is always a word space in addition to the `\hfill` between the boxes, so you are relying on that space fitting in to the .06\textwidth left over from the 2*.47

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So you mean I should put a `%` after like this: `\end{minipage}%`, because as far as I could tell there is a `%` after `\end{minipage}`, but on the next line (except for final `\end{minipage}`. So does this make a difference then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2 `\\` from the top boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,tikzmark}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\myswitch{Not for production!}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mysignature}{ m m O{0} O{.8\linewidth} O{0pt} O{0pt} }{
    \IfEq{\myswitch}{Not for production!}
        {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
            \path [anchor=south west,draw,red,dashed] ($ (pic cs:#1) + (0,-3mm) $) rectangle (\linewidth,4cm) node [anchor=center,pos=.5,font=\bfseries\large] {UNSIGNED};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
        {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
            \node [anchor=south west,rotate=#3,xshift=#5,yshift=#6] at (pic cs:#1) {\includegraphics[width=#4]{#2}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{A-sig-left}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Dr. Joe Schmoe\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Managing Director\\
\mysignature{A-sig-left}{sig1.eps}[1][\linewidth][0mm][-12mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{A-sig-right}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Billybob Janice\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Head of Peanut Gallery\\
\mysignature{A-sig-right}{sig2.eps}[1][.8\linewidth][5mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{B-sig-left}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Dr. Joe Schmoe\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize Managing Director\\
\mysignature{B-sig-left}{sig1.eps}[1][\linewidth][0mm][-12mm]
}
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\tikzmark{B-sig-right}\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\vspace{2mm}
Billybob Janice\\[.5\baselineskip]
{\footnotesize
Head of Peanut Gallery\\
}
\mysignature{B-sig-right}{sig2.eps}[1][.8\linewidth][5mm]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```